# ASP.net Core Web Application Template is missing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to follow this tutorial:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start

However, when I get to the Create a Razor Web App section, there is no template in my install of VS2017.

I have both the .net core and asp.net and web dev workloads installed.  Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: It seems I had an OS issue that caused updates to fail.  Have rebuilt the PC and all working as expected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had an OS issue that caused updates to fail. Have rebuilt the PC and all working as expected now. Very much a sledgehammer approach, but this was something fundamentally wrong with the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Open Visual Studio (assuming its 2017) and go to: Tools > Extensions and Updates

Click "ASP.Net and web development", then select the appropriate Individual Components in the right hand pane. You'll find components such as ".Net Core 2.0 Development tools" and ASP.Net web development tools"

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the latest update for your Visual Studio installation?

- Head to Add or Remove Programs
- find Visual Studio
- Click Modify
- Allow the installer to update
- Install any updates that are missing

[image]

On top of that, do you have the latest version of the [.NET Core SDK](http://dot.net/core)?